# KDE5 kate wont open remote ssh location (fish) of currently opened file

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, kde5, kate

Since moving to the new Linux Mint 18.1 the KDE version that comes with is KDE5.
In KDE4 when using kate on a remote file using fish:// when asking to open another file it would have opened the location of the currently open file, which is super helpful because you don't have to go all the way again just to open the file adjacent your currently open file.

In KDE5 in kate I couldn't find any setting to make it happen again. Everytime I work on a file and wish to open a diffrent file on the same location the kate opens at my home folder and than I have to go to the remote folder all the way.

I know I could mount the remote location using sshfs but I'd rather not. Anyone has any idea if I could force-downgrade to KDE4 or change a setting on the kate to get that feature back?

**Edit:** Found out that while trying to save a new file it will open the remote directory